# jenkins with copy artifact plugin without maven from GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins, websphere

I am trying to deploy a war file into WAS8.5 with GitHub. at first I am specifying "EAR Path" with the war file in "Websphere Deployment" option. Then I made some changes in eclipse workspace and pushed into GitHub. Jenkins is checking for latest build but unable to deploy the same in Server. I have used [copy artifact plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin), but still nothing happening. I may be wrong in configurations or something. I am getting the following exception:

```
Copied 0 artifacts from "simplewebapp" build number 20
ERROR: Failed to copy artifacts from simplewebapp with filter: *.war
Archiving artifacts
Finished: FAILURE
```

and in `\jobs\simplewebapp\builds\lastSuccessfulBuild\archive\SimpleWebApp`, am unable to see any archive file. How can i achieve it without Maven?
Kindly show me with some examples.

[jenkinone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zk7jJ.png)
[jenkintwo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OO98i.png)

Comment: On your build job, did you archive (as an artefact) your war file?

Comment: I just have added war file in project specified job. and in builds/buildnumber/archive folder, i can see the project structure, not as EAR/WAR.

Comment: I am using the default project option called "Build a free-style software project" and i have added just a * symbol into "Post-build Actions" where you can select the option archive the artifacts.

i have searched on google but whenever I use *.war or modules/*/*.war it doesn't work.

but when I use just a * symbol it only downloads the github contents of my project into the workspace but it doesn't compile into a actually WAR/EAR artifact.

Comment: Can you detail your Jenkins workflow? Just to understand where is your source code, how do you compile it, where you want to deploy your WAR/EAR files, ... Next, I'll be able to give you a better answer :)

Comment: So you want to build a project hosted in GitHub, archive the artifacts (WAR or EAR files) and push these artifacts to your WebSphere server?

Comment: I have created pjct in eclipse and configured with GitHub. In jenkins, created a "free style project" and added GitHub URL. checked "Build when a change is pushed to GitHub" and also "Poll SCM". Installed "Copy Artifact plugin", and done cnfgrtns below:
1. Project Name: simplewebapp
2. which build: Latest Successful
3. artifacts to copy: **/*.ear
4. Target Directory: D:\wars
in post build action: added ** to files to archive options.

For WAS cnfgrtn I have added, SimpleWebApp.war in EAR Path and made rmng cnfgrtns. I can able to deploy the war, but not the changes frm GitHub. Please Help!!

Comment: Can you post some screen copies of your Jenkins job configuration? (in your initial post)

Comment: I am unable to upload it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78204/discussion-between-bruno-lavit-and-swetha).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a final answer, I recommend to host your project code in GitHub, to use Jenkins/Maven to build your project and to publish the EAR/WAR file to WebSphere using this [deployer plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/WebSphere+Deployer+Plugin).

Comment: Thank you. I will install Maven in my machine.